# populate datatable from a local json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatables

I am trying to populate my datatable using a JSON file (`jsontext.json`) I tried almost all the resources but can't work this one out. I have tried all the stackoverflow resources. This question is different than the one that are posted.

If I could just get the JSON file into the my jsonObject then the rest I can figure out.

The Json file is stored in my c:\path\jsontext.json

Here is the json file

```
[
    {
        "Identifier": "1",
        "Label": "pratik",
        "Categories": "Standard",
        "UpdatedBy": "lno",
        "UpdatedAt": "01-02-2013"

    },
    {
        "Identifier": "2",
        "Label": "2013",
        "Categories": "Standard",
        "UpdatedBy": "lno",
        "UpdatedAt": "01-02-2013"
    }
]
```

I tried the following js code to get the file into jsonObject

```
var myObject;
    $.ready(function(){
        myObject={};
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/jsontext.json', function(data){
        /* here I have tried using both the paths the c:\path\jsontext.json and the one above */
         myObject=data;
        });
    });
```

Once i have it into the JsonObject I can use the following code to populate the datatable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#example').dataTable
        ( {
            "sScrollY": "200px",
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            aaData:myObject,

            "aoColumns":
                    [
                        { "mData": "Identifier" },
                        { "mData": "Label" },
                        { "mData": "Categories" },
                        { "mData": "UpdatedBy" },
                        { "mData": "UpdatedAt" },
                        { "sClass": "getimage"},
                        { "sClass": "editimage"},
                        { "sClass": "deleteimage"}


                    ]
        });
    });
```

Here is my html body in my jsp page

```
<body id="dt_example">
<div id="container">

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
<ul>
    <li> <a href="addedit.jsp">Add Code Edit</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Import</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Export</a></li>
</ul>
<tr>
    <th>Identifier</th>
    <th>Label</th>
    <th>Categories</th>
    <th>UpdatedBy</th>
    <th>UpdatedAt</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Data 3</td>
    <td>Row 1 Data 4</td>
    <td>Row 1 Data 5</td>
    <td class="getimage"><a href="addedit.jsp"></a></td>
    <td class="editimage"></td>
    <td class="deleteimage"></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

can Anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: It should be a json object according to the jquery documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ getJSON will do the conversion from string to a json object automatically.

Comment: nope , I cant get the data table to populate.

Comment: Make sure that your json file is accessible by your web server. Javascript has security issues with accessing local files on a client machine.

Comment: According to the documentation it says "data" is a json Object but i cant even get it to print.

Comment: yes I can Access it with my web browser

Comment: Do you get anything when doing console.log(data); in the success of your request?

Comment: No i even tried console.log(data); there is nothing on the screen. except the default datatable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31737/discussion-between-dslagle-and-user2415379)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you see the server response in developer tools you can find the data that is received. As far as I have worked with the dataTables, the json file must contain a "key" for the whole data, otherwise it wont have any reference.

Try modifying your json as follows:

```
{
  "mydata":[

  {
    "Identifier": "1",
    "Label": "pratik",
    "Categories": "Standard",
    "UpdatedBy": "lno",
    "UpdatedAt": "01-02-2013"

  },
  {
    "Identifier": "2",
    "Label": "2013",
    "Categories": "Standard",
    "UpdatedBy": "lno",
    "UpdatedAt": "01-02-2013"
  }
 ]
}
```

if you want to use the json object other than "aaData", you can use ["sAjaxDataProp"](https://datatables.net/usage/options) of the datatable to specify the respective object.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem could be that your ajax is loading and setting the myObject variable but it is done after Datatables initialized so it does not get the updated myObject variable after your request has finished. You could do something like this to fix that:

```
var myObject;
$.ready(function(){
    myObject={};
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/jsontext.json', function(data){
    /* here I have tried using both the paths the c:\path\jsontext.json and the one above */
     myObject=data;
    $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData(myObject);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replys every one I got the answer I tried out thanks though.

```
var someData=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("populate-holdingBin").innerHTML);
    oTables=$('#someReport').dataTable
        ({
            "bJQueryUI":true,
            "bScrollCollapse":true,
            aaData:someData,
            "aoColumns":
                   [ ...etc etc.............................. ]
         });
```